# sys.setrecursionlimit not working in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, recursion, jupyter-notebook

I am using this code in jupyter notebook in order to download SEC files. On some point kernel dies. I guess that it is due to recurssion limit error, so I tried `sys.setrecursionlimit(20000)` to exceed the limit, but seems it doesnt work, as kernel keeps dying.However I used it in Google Colab, and it worked. Please help

```
from sec_edgar_downloader import Downloader
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(3000000)

dl = Downloader()

def download_all(cik_list):
   for i in cik_list:
       for j in ["10-K","10-Q"]:
           dl.get(j, i)
```

Comment: While I'm not familiar with this library, I can say that `sys.setrecursionlimit(3000000)` is almost certainly broken code. It's not possible to just invent a stack size of 3 million and expect the OS to tolerate that. You'll likely crash the interpreter. Secondly, seems unlikely that a downloader would use recursion in the first place, so it's more likely that there's a memory error. `dl.get` looks like it does nothing with the result, so I'd anticipate that the garbage collector would prevent a memory error. Is this really the whole code? What's `cik_list`, please? Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen when I run this code without `sys.setrecursionlimit(3000000)` in Colab, it returned recursion limit error, after which I entered that line and it run without error. I tried it in jupyter notebook, inserted different numbers started from 20000, instead of 3 mln, but it didnt worked and on some step kernel died.
`cik_list` is a list of CIK numbers, which are unique for each company, starting with zeros and with lenght of 10. `for` loop iteretas over that list and for each CIK downloads it reports.